# How to finish this LAG calculation in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have month and value columns in a table,like

```
Month              Value        Market
2010/01            100            1  
2010/02            200            1
2010/03            300            1
2010/04            400            1
2010/05            500            1
2010/01            100            2  
2010/02            200            2
2010/03            300            2
2010/04            400            2
2010/05            500            2
```

What I want to do is get new Month and Value combinations using (value in month(n-1)+value in month(n))/2=value in month n, also this calculation is based on market column, it group by market number. So, for the above example, the new month and value combination should be

```
Month                Value         Market
2010/01            null               1
2010/02            (100+200)/2        1
2010/03            (200+300)/2        1
2010/04            (300+400)/2        1
2010/05            (400+500)/2        1
2010/01            null               2
2010/02            (100+200)/2        2
2010/03            (200+300)/2        2
2010/04            (300+400)/2        2
2010/05            (400+500)/2        2
```

Do you know how to achieve it in Oracle? Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there is no gap in your data, you can use [`LAG`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions082.htm#i1327527):

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS (
  2     SELECT DATE '2010-01-01' mon, 100 val FROM dual UNION ALL
  3     SELECT DATE '2010-02-01' mon, 200 val FROM dual UNION ALL
  4     SELECT DATE '2010-03-01' mon, 300 val FROM dual UNION ALL
  5     SELECT DATE '2010-04-01' mon, 400 val FROM dual UNION ALL
  6     SELECT DATE '2010-05-01' mon, 500 val FROM dual
  7  )
  8  SELECT mon, (LAG(val) OVER (ORDER BY mon) + val) / 2 avg_val FROM DATA;

MON            AVG_VAL
----------- ----------
01/01/2010  
01/02/2010         150
01/03/2010         250
01/04/2010         350
01/05/2010         450
```

However, if there is a gap the result might not be what you expect. In that case, you can either use a self-join or narrow the windowing clause:

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS (
  2     SELECT DATE '2010-01-01' mon, 100 val FROM dual UNION ALL
  3     SELECT DATE '2010-02-01' mon, 200 val FROM dual UNION ALL
  4     SELECT DATE '2010-03-01' mon, 300 val FROM dual UNION ALL
  5     /* gap ! */
  6     SELECT DATE '2010-05-01' mon, 400 val FROM dual UNION ALL
  7     SELECT DATE '2010-06-01' mon, 500 val FROM dual
  8  )
  9  SELECT mon, (first_value(val)
 10                 OVER (ORDER BY mon
 11                       RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '1' MONTH PRECEDING
 12                                 AND INTERVAL '1' MONTH PRECEDING)
 13               + val) / 2 avg_val
 14    FROM DATA;

MON            AVG_VAL
----------- ----------
01/01/2010  
01/02/2010         150
01/03/2010         250
01/05/2010  
01/06/2010         450
```

Comment: Vincent. Thanks for your nice answer. I edit my question, what if I add another condition, this calculation is based on market number, how to recalculate it? Thanks!

Comment: Use the partition clause, see [Analytic functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174). For instance: `LAG(val) OVER (PARTITION BY market ORDER BY mon)`.

Answer (score 3):

This does it:

```
SQL> select month,
  2         (value+lag(value) over (order by month))/2 as value
  3* from t1

MONTH           VALUE
---------- ----------
2010/01
2010/02           150
2010/03           250
2010/04           350
2010/05           450

5 rows selected.
```

Comment: Hi Tony. Thanks for your answer. I edit my question,this calculation is based on market, do u know how to solve it? Thanks!

Comment: Just change the `over()` clause to `over (partition by market order by month)`